# HTTP 404 when using Differential Query on Microsoft Graph

Tags: powershell, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on a PowerShell Module for Microsoft Graph access.
The last days I integrated Differential Queries feature, which looks like this (I removed the other lines of code for simplicity)

```
$Uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta"
$Headers = @{}
$Headers.Add('Authorization',$AuthToken.token_type + ' ' + $AuthToken.access_token)
$Responses = @()
while ($Uri.Length -gt 0)
{
  Add-TraceLine -F_Type $MSG_INFO -F_Text "$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name): Calling '$($Uri)'"
  $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers
  $Responses += $Response
  $Uri = $Response.'@odata.nextlink'
}
```

It is working without any issues with my dev-tenant, but when using it with a larger prod-tenant (around 2000 users) after some "paging recalls" I get a 404 error.

```
12.01.2017-17:34:49: <INFO> - Get-AuthToken: AuthToken successfully retrieved
12.01.2017-17:34:49: <INFO> - Get-DirectoryDelta: Calling 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta'
12.01.2017-17:34:52: <INFO> - Get-DirectoryDelta: Calling 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$skiptoken=pqwSUjGY...LEt9NU'
12.01.2017-17:34:55: <INFO> - Get-DirectoryDelta: Calling 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$skiptoken=pqwSUjGY...-YFO04'
12.01.2017-17:34:59: <INFO> - Get-DirectoryDelta: Calling 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$skiptoken=Ea-8SYD1...utlDfs'
12.01.2017-17:35:02: <INFO> - Get-DirectoryDelta: Calling 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$skiptoken=rYOEcH4S...CyiqGw'
12.01.2017-17:35:06: <INFO> - Get-DirectoryDelta: Calling 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$skiptoken=pqwSUjGY...qCQ2Bw'
12.01.2017-17:35:10: <INFO> - Get-DirectoryDelta: Calling 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$skiptoken=pqwSUjGY...pMe6nQ'
12.01.2017-17:35:13: <INFO> - Get-DirectoryDelta: Calling 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$skiptoken=Ea-8SYD1...M1-hqA'
12.01.2017-17:35:17: <INFO> - Get-DirectoryDelta: Calling 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$skiptoken=pqwSUjGY...XpIjLQ'
12.01.2017-17:35:19: <INFO> - Get-DirectoryDelta: Calling 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$skiptoken=pqwSUjGY...rSTlUE'
12.01.2017-17:35:22: <INFO> - Get-DirectoryDelta: Calling 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$skiptoken=pqwSUjGY...XScaFk'
12.01.2017-17:35:25: <INFO> - Get-DirectoryDelta: Calling 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$skiptoken=rYOEcH4SBvAbBlMmovFlUmEWcRpD3JGmdLx1AavA9i1hdAmi16prEydV034jKvF9jlwlRi0yEQ3C3nO31HjIyDSmVYeq__2yrGCn8Hyt76YWRrLrd-Jn7yxLBkbWKnadJaoLGom5dwAq9294oQuqv4aFKDjZa_NlGyttgLLF6l6mNHXMxSBRB5QOR-zaFosyk2S-5_vAeibPer0MufNUECzL-qTxE5KGrTdjxkbg5ZdSRggf3IgclrVIii7wWDd_2MoTwy3oZtsbqoPKHR4zt6n_W95yZfgHl0sDK_ZZa-s86gJnIg7RgETBuJQrSc7OnUjn2yIoBsf-5qfXqUxGLNCm4_FJjFJsD83wdZkLvjgVe42iFj98Qf96NAkHeZ68qPcFcLn0OUZ8LW_nDQHF7h43GcHT5JHduh-84KaeUEQOglbKWCGE7e7yajoGlIW1H4zB0gQWbPrXAobunXxviZsj3ux3yl75PQR1XpM0FKG1ZRA_u3DVULsans1aoEglLGNUFE25S5Vv-rqJrcxZaEtuVbTU729rTdaH5Nvn08NseOZNvILYtCPeRSRSdwM23OJm1PPj3d_OzwmMRVsh3q5Akv43fZhgC7fDoK1mCeuAz2yYD-iIts1yxt9TpcaVPNp51h7l6b8XQlXzVek53KX7apm5PBSaPPe0Sjm9qfL-Rog6X8L2Tv59EbWcOIEGjhxk0GWqAC9QcS-RiZTRtz2iet_dW3u_1j7EO2AQ_tg8-U7rjm7qW9P_0eycpQSL7i7dKDe5344HQh4mdgd1Iw.4SkFtoIP0vQ0j4vslu2Uo62uyagAr1kaaIOHpWd_tHY'
12.01.2017-17:35:26: <INFO> - Get-DirectoryDelta: Calling 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$skiptoken=ueiGuewhVuxumZOebVNojq9UANNVEmv6YVf_RAUSm5z-3-ssMusdi3COamnFhPynAsJSdieCT6G_XMWBzheuBCSXGkbqaAlioKkvvU6tqqHcdbwdrGUW3ZDZAq8JgE6idLSPG0GXSvAuicqL_hc3orDenWuSAy49dX3dhs_PmXA83di7kVv2C7qObXU8HD69UaYrLnHrOg8XS-dFp58smRUoymocmRw5mQMEIQOtyoez3qqZtidMdKhI0KSkU4gbRO30bBQMTeQiX5mFp9040Cvzzmq-ItrHUdZmRn-RJzOQVLqLDOBWR9uY3_DQlOi7bH8MXYzibdgPX7DeaX6fiVIE8Z4yL9o12M2gRO9CK0s6OuS7UBGdSHB8a0c48UcN2Z7sNA6JTq-rPeA-Lm7AJT6mBREhiDE21wqhfVdMKhYEqntEsW6aFP2adbPN3wZVaRdBZG4-VTisT_VHKaOqaHr2xIVTc5qjZXQXjPPFcFNTRUQukQ1PmBcRytSnJmfFvDUkYt68HpqfVcnZoMiHxIbnNFhOjJFIcN-CmkSTw-b1UWaRqnlNXM1hkp_r20e3RWcxCYeAtLe5ZQpNdPKW5IdWDPTqft7Aj6QI-KmgNKlSuyqf5aXLnatSuiUeO1twa_9zUn8qdv9yUodmEjG8wgq5jaaxeHHnDlRYoGukDvu8-DaWZrJ-JwxznL_-MJo5NGMqT-fRDWiHPGdMmEbAl-xnKB825P8aDpd5H8AGAq-xWD8gJi_iiTnvkPu3XTLmlhz33uoAufxLSMltCbkPc3l5AR0dtMN8dXhXXwUfmjvJkAZSPIxtJ4fuBoi4z-4TASmRorBVvekYpVvFdh1hhgN8I_JqY3hzGt5T46PIlcIC_14GOXKg2Eou1ej3njZFgbt2xA6gIltcMhL6Vh_IH-bO4F3n2BXxpiJl7VwqTdmqP9NRtF5rGKbEleFzCd6WwxLUvV36h5lyfqkrBKDUiYTKqXdRtRX0NXxkx4D8CNeviO4F8cKEL4U-OidM0Z55m7NYTVaAtq0hF43wz_nNPf6ywcx3gDPfhTxOXeFJ5SGGpbg4gTV3ChhehKQK9cSUGOD02u3vTU_vXim0ClrVixEqUfasAEIOlwtw90TrJoeN-ynO0MoYCDo7UfgQVqxXIvBliwMIiEQ6bHCmerZc9lU4S_e_zIs5EHKBOicnsihQtJ2cgh_iBfILPN1ULfTTbVmCygElIBVeJf1YojxRcYI3TlGNtDapt7_LyRpE-kf-gxJn96XoKXzqNu9SSbpLWO31Zu95YmiRLHtqDagAvpfjAOuu2ffweFCuA83bZKqWPw3m7aX3OmIKHqYmjqy9s--jmuez231MROGdY-NlMdnf3I1JcWaxoEbh0DdwBNtF6lM4pDewqphDWbiiLYOvIyfDRliRGZAshidZDr8IJ7yI6uKuEIGwmiVl3seJ_Emmq53TiSUm4ysY1noRM76UMYoiV7PtZNBKSjiGJWSlHpK5xGQUyfYHeQnuyUm1RBtuXrnnzSHxWDl13YHBxTXjE4L0pImKMO__by6ZD5QV31Myygz2BYikTxF5a7G70pgVuFa-Fe25yVERnxA_YvDsxBHVrGDHMSJtRbbbxfzd7xUv5L6EQRkQwoz-f4p5e4vTOogTJYBdNIuzRoJWriK5i56R8VKAVG2GrST0hgZVFQhVPr_w9TRuRgGnsza8i04F-P43kK2AlqEmz96SSioqHPCxnGFdqmnlmUZp6Do6Oa07QJxPlG8kE_VY4qryVAWe9usqTGVuCIJP5QGjf043YYMfzJb62I-rMjYth-fFfrMdzmdkrpbGCVm9JvJhB30odBh9b9ptoJgFJOqcGklwvnwxxBeZI1v_XDL_UrPR5GRlvTZYW4_BgocbQI9BKB9qTwcASY5WPYnRVZ6pSjqnJ0gmfajFOqCnsFJ6kW-oQqbupPM2VptlTHi7Un3I1g9bq-eJU1rsuHXvw22ACjP-LpaHl
```

I simplified all URIs but the last 2.
What you can see here, is that the last URI (which is failing) is a lot longer than the others.
Any ideas whats happening here?
Thanks
Stefan

Comment: Sorry that you are hitting an issue. To help us trace the issue can you add a more explicit error, please? When you get the 404, you should also get an error message, client request Id and timestamp - we need all of these please.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get these parameters from the response?

Comment: They should be in the HTTP header (response). (Client-Request-Id and Timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're sending skipToken as a deltaToken. Could you please share Client-Request-Id and Timestamp, they're available in the response headers.

Comment: It looks like the info is missing when using the PowerShell method "Invoke-RestMethod"...

Comment: As described [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/it-it/docs/concepts/delta_query_users.htm) delta links should look like this

    https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/delta?$deltatoken=oEcOySpF_hWYmTIUZBOIfPzcwisr_rPe8o9M54L45qEXQGmvQC6T2dbL-9O7nSU-njKhFiGlAZqewNAThmCVnNxqPu5gOBegrm1CaVZ-ZtFZ2tPOAO98OD9y0ao460

The Uri I get before the error includes the skiptoken, as you can see in the first post.